# What is ! and ??= mean in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am learning Dart, I saw some sample, but I have no idea some of the sign use for:

```
 void push(E value) {
  head = Node(value: value, next: head);
  tail ??= head;
 }
```

**What is ??= mean?**

```
void append(E value) {
 // 1
 if (isEmpty) {
 push(value);
 return;
 }
 // 2
 tail!.next = Node(value: value);
 // 3
 tail = tail!.next;
}
```

**What is ! at tail! mean?**

Comment: I recommend you go though this code-lab: https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety which explains all these concepts.

Comment: If someone has to use `!` this way in a sample, I would stay away from it. It is not code you want to learn from.

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `??=`: Also called the null-aware assignment. This operator assigns the value to the variable on its left, only if that variable is currently `null`;
2. `!`: It is used to reverse the result. You can think of that simply like a "not operator".

Comment: Your second description would normally be correct but not in the context of the question. It is not `!` at the beginning of a boolean but rather `!` after a null-able variable. The meaning of this `!` are instead that we force Dart into thinking the null-able variable are non-nullable. Dart will add a runtime check to ensure you are telling the truth and crash the program if the variable would end up being `null`.